# obscure error in index file

Tags: makeindex

I reduce my problem to the following example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{makeidx}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

\index{j}
\nocite{Salsa}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem{Salsa}
Salsa
\end{thebibliography}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

I compile the file with the command `latexmk --pdf` and get the following error:

```
! A <box> was supposed to be here.
<to be read again> 
                   \def 
l.5 \end{theindex}
```

line numbers referring to the `ind` generated file which reads as:

```
\begin{theindex}

  \item j, \hyperpage{1}

\end{theindex}
```

The error can be reproduced on the docker image: ghcr.io/xu-cheng/texlive-full

Comment: Works for me when using `pdflatex` + `makeindex` + `pdflatex` (via `arara`).

Comment: The problem is the usual one: `classicthesis` loads `hyperref` at a wrong time.